# I need a way to include a http-server

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, http, html-framework-7

I'm working on a webSite to apk using Framework7, i'm facing cross origin error. XMLHttpRequest cannot load

here's the error I have.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xxx/start.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. on framework7.min.js:21

Sorry for my english.

Comment: don't develop via file urls, then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is happening 'cause you are opening the `html` document directly from the browser. To fix this, you'll need to serve your code into a web-server and access it on Localhost.

So you can either install a web-server in your local PC or upload the model somewhere else and change the URL to `http://example.com/path/to/model`